Questions solely in Latin?
I recently asked two questions in Latin:
Exsistitne in lingua Latina verbum pro die post cras? 
Estne in lingua Latina verbum pro die ante heri? 
In the first question, @Kingshorsey suggested that we should have a rule against such questions. What do you think about that?
@JoonasIlmavirta said that this question has already been asked, but very long ago, so that it can and should be re-asked. We decided that questions in Latin only are permitted, because we are a Latin site. Do we still agree with this policy?

How does this Meta question not answer yours, too?

@cmw As I commented under the question on main, I think it's fine to reask questions like this on meta. The previous one is old and its answer doesn't have the force of an official policy. It would certainly be better to make the relation of this new question to that old one explicit instead of leaving it without mention. As it stands, it's a duplicate in my eyes, but as "do we still stand by that old opinion?" it would not be.

@JoonasIlmavirta I didn't see that comment. That would help to explain it, but this question really needs some contextualization first. FlatAssembler: can you fix this question so it's not a duplicate?

@cmw OK, I did.

There's alsoa different, more recent question (within six months on Nov 23 2023) Should we allow questions that are posed in a language other than English or Latin?  with responses implying posing questions in either English or Latin is still expected to fine
